# Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I get this error when trying to plot the following chart:

```
var chart1 = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart1',
  data: {
    url: '../CSV/Chart_data/grade_year.csv',
    x: 'YEAR',
    type: 'bar',
  },
  size: {
    height: 370
  },
  grid: {
    y: {
      show: true,
      lines: [{
        value: 5,
        text: 'Passed grade'
      }, ]
    }
  },
  bar: {
    width: {
      ratio: 0.7
    }
  }
});
```

The grade_year.csv file is:

```
AC_YEAR,MEAN
2010,5.387
2011,5.63
2012,5.258
2013,5.355
2014,5.235
2015,4.892
```

I do not understand what is wrong... The complete error that I get is:

> c3.js:1097 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function
>       at ChartInternal.c3_chart_internal_fn.initParams (c3.js:1097)
>       at ChartInternal.c3_chart_internal_fn.init (c3.js:1065)
>       at new Chart (c3.js:1018)
>       at Object.c3.generate (c3.js:1043)
>       at Charts.js:1

Comment: probably the chart lib that you use when creating the instance internally is calling the intermediate value or something, you don't call it directly right?

Comment: No, I do not call it directly. Should I?

Comment: im asking because the lib could be expecting another data from you, what is the lib your using?

Comment: I have the same issue using c3 with vue js ```Error in event handler for "init": "TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function"```